# Getting all custom posts with a certain category

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, categories

I'm apparently retarded, and i have a hard time figuring out a simple task as getting all posts with a certain category. I tried:

- query_posts()
- New Query()

but im struggling to get something out of them

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'                     => 'fb',
    'fbcate_category'   => array(35),
    'order'                         => 'DESC', 
    'posts_per_page'                => -1,
);

$posts_array = new WP_Query($args);
```

I've tried similar with query_posts(), but I don't get anything out except a empty array of that either.

Comment: please post complete code.

Comment: What do you mean with the complete code? what more do i need to get posts for a specific category? i can throw in all the HTML if you wish, but i dont think you would want all that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$blabla = new Query($args);` should be 
`$blabla = new WP_Query($args);`

**UPDATE**
Your actual code should be something like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'fb',
    'tax_query'         => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'fbcate_category',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => '35',
        ),
    ),
    'order'             => 'DESC', 
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
);

$posts_array = new WP_Query($args);
```

Where `taxonomy` is your taxonomy name.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Still returns an empty array :(

Comment: one more thing. value of cat should be `int` not an array. so, you need to change that line too

Comment: Still not working :( its a custom post and a custom taxonomy, does that matter?

Comment: Yes, That matters. you need to put value of the `post_type` as well. It defaults to `post` . More details about the WP_Query class can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: i have edit'ed op, that brings me some of the posts but not all of them :S

Comment: Updated answer. Please check with that code and let me know the result.